# Can I use an Optional (where the Optional will always be not null) within a request parameter object?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to use Java 8's `Optional` from within a request parameter object. Is there any way to guarantee that the value of the `Optional` is not null, even if the parameter is not defined in the request?

In the following example, if `value` is given, there is no problem. *However*, if no `value` is defined in the request, a null pointer exception is thrown because `requestDto.value` is null.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String doTest(RequestDto requestDto) {
        return requestDto.getValue().orElse("it doesn't exist");
    }

    public static class RequestDto {

        private Optional<String> value;

        public Optional<String> getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(Optional<String> value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

    }
}
```

In a working example, without using an object, there is no problem if `value` is not defined in the request:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String doTest(@RequestParam("value") Optional<String> value) {
        return value.orElse("it doesn't exist");
    }

}
```

Comment: A solution that I have is to set `Optional<String> value = Optional.empty()` but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner solution.

Comment: That's the thing about `Optional`. It was never meant to be used as method parameter. It was intended as a return value. In that spirit I would suggest to use a normal String and do a null check as you usually would have done. There is actually a bug ticket for this in the OpenJDK bug tracker: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8167981